# Combination of rows in numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, combinations, numpy-ndarray

I have the following numpy.ndarray

```
S=np.array([[[ -0.6,  -0.2,   0. ],
             [-60. ,   2. ,   0. ],
             [  6. , -20. ,   0. ]],

            [[ -0.4,  -0.8,   0. ],
             [-40. ,   8. ,   0. ],
             [  4. , -80. ,   0. ]]])
```

I want to find all the possible combinations of sum of each row (sum of individual elements of a row **except the last column**) of S[0,:,:] with each row of S[1,:,:], i.e., my desired result is (order does not matter):

```
array([[-1,     -1],
       [-40.6,   7.8],
       [3.4,   -80.2],
       [-60.4,   1.2],
       [-100,    10],
       [-56,    -78],
       [5.6,   -20.8],
       [-34,    -12],
       [10,    -100]])
```

which is a 9-by-2 array resulting from 9 possible combinations of S[0,:,:] and S[1,:,:]. Although I have used a particular shape of S here, the shape may vary, i.e., for

```
x,y,z = np.shape(S)
```

in the above problem, x=2, y=3, and z=3, but these values may vary. Therefore, I am seeking for a generalized version.

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

(Please no for loops if possible. It is pretty trivial then.)

Comment: And, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MrNobody33 I am quite clueless without for loops. I am quite new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcast like this:

```
(S[0,:,None, :-1] +  S[1,None,:,:-1]).reshape(-1,2)
```

Output:

```
array([[  -1. ,   -1. ],
       [ -40.6,    7.8],
       [   3.4,  -80.2],
       [ -60.4,    1.2],
       [-100. ,   10. ],
       [ -56. ,  -78. ],
       [   5.6,  -20.8],
       [ -34. ,  -12. ],
       [  10. , -100. ]])
```

Comment: can this be generalized? I mean here x=2 for x,y,z = np.shape(S). Can this be generalized for arbitrary shape of S?